# Monthly / daily / Week query data and Column as name

Tags: mysql

I have a table of orders

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_main` (
`om_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
`om_raren` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'serial number',
`om_total` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'money',
`om_freight` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'freight',
`om_amount` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'money + freight',
`om_status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order Status：1）Unpaid 2）Paid 3）Cancel 4）Payment     
success,
`om_created` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'create time',
PRIMARY KEY (`om_id`)
)
```

I want three query methods:

1) Year by year

2) month by month

3) week by week

I hope the result will be:

```
AllRow    AllTotal    date

  2        100         1
  10       1000       10
  10       1000       12
```

AllRow: items Count ,count(*)

AllTotal:sum(om_total)

date:Any month or Any year or Any week

I do not have any idea to do this thing

I hope you give me advice, thank you

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this for Year:

```
select count(*) as AllRow, sum(om_total) as AllTotal,YEAR(om_created) as d from order_main group by YEAR(om_created)
```

For Month

```
select count(*) as AllRow, sum(om_total) as AllTotal,Month(om_created) as m from order_main group by year(om_created),month(om_created)
```

For Week

```
select count(*) as AllRow, sum(om_total) as AllTotal,WEEK(om_created) as week from order_main group by year(om_created),WEEK(om_created)
```

Note: Query is not tested.

Comment: it's work  ,  but I hope that every year there will be a Row ,This is where my distress(= = ...)